# SVN Repository Monitoring Tool for Mac OS X

Tags: svn, macos

Is anyone aware of an OS X tool to monitor SVN repositories for new commits? I am looking for an OS X equivalent to [CommitMonitor](http://tools.tortoisesvn.net/CommitMonitor) of the Windows world.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6):

Found [SVN notifier](http://lab.arc90.com/2008/04/02/svn-notifier), but it does not work on SVN through SSH :( And it's only for one repo.

Comment: you can add 2 dashboard widgets for different repositories. So it works for more then one repo. BTW, thanks for the link, nice widget! Works with free version of Growl 1.2.2

Comment: broken "download" link

Answer (score -1):

I always use [zigversion](http://zigzig.com/) for everything related to svn.

Comment: Thank you, I tried it. ZigVersion is a full-scale SVN client, as opposed to a separate memory-resident repository location monitoring utility. It has also failed a 15-minute test for me, being unable to import one of my working copies, and failing to connect to an svn+ssh server. I also couldn't quickly find a way to have ZigVersion use SSH key authentication. Furthermore, it isn't too apparent whether it can monitor and notify the user of changes to a specified repository location.

Comment: Although on the zigversion main page, something is mentioned about notifications, I have never used the notification part, so not sure how to use it.
It is a full scale client indeed, so if you have memory restrictions, you should be looking for something else.
svn + ssh works for me with zigversion. I remember having some problems with it, but don't know exactly anymore how I solved it. However, http://zigzig.com/content/view/23/28/ might help.

Comment: SVN Notifier (http://lab.arc90.com/2008/04/02/svn-notifier/) is almost there, but I couldn't make it work with a repository that's only accessible via svn+ssh.